# Doctrine2 Many to Many - не происходит запись

Tags: symfony2, doctrine2, symfony3

Добрый день.
Работаю в связи ManyToMany.

Есть два объекта: Service и User.

```
class Service
{

...

/**
 * @var $mentors
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="services", cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $mentors;


/**
 * Constructor
 */
public function __construct()
{    
    $this->mentors = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 * Add mentors
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\User $mentor
 * @return Service
 */
public function addMentors(\AppBundle\Entity\User $mentor)
{
    $this->mentors->add($mentor);
}

/**
 * Remove mentor
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\User $mentor
 */
public function removeMentors(\AppBundle\Entity\User $mentor)
{
    $this->mentors->removeElement($mentor);
}

/**
 * Get mentors
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
 */
public function getMentors()
{
    return $this->mentors;
}

}
```

И User:

```
class User extends BaseUser
{
...



/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\AdminBundle\Entity\Service", mappedBy="mentors", cascade={"persist"})
 */
protected $services;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->services = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}


/**
 * Add services
 * @param \App\AdminBundle\Entity\Service $service
 * @return User
 */
public function addServices(\App\AdminBundle\Entity\Service $service)
{
    $this->services->add($service);
    $service->addMentors($this);
}

/**
 * Remove service
 * @param \App\AdminBundle\Entity\Service $service
 */
public function removeServices(\App\AdminBundle\Entity\Service $service)
{
    $this->services->removeElement($service);
}

/**
 * Get services
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getServices()
{
    return $this->services;
}
}
```

Обратную связь для класса User сделал по инструкции.
Если делаю изменения со стороны Service - все работает отлично.
Но если пытаюсь добавить сервис со стороны Участников, то уже не работает, хотя обратная связь есть:

```
public function addService(\App\AdminBundle\Entity\Service $service)
{
$service->addMentor($this);
$this->services[] = $service;
}
```

Содержимое UserController.php

```
public function editAction(Request $request, User $user)
{      
    $editForm = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\UserType', $user);
    $editForm->handleRequest($request);

    if ($editForm->isSubmitted() && $editForm->isValid()) {
        $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('user_edit', array('id' => $user->getId()));
    }

    return $this->render('user/edit.html.twig', array(
        'user' => $user,
        'edit_form' => $editForm->createView()          
    ));
}
```

Как должна выглядеть запись в контроллере? Перепробовал уже все возможное, изменения данных пользователя происходит, но сервисы не приписываются.

UserType

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('services',null,[            
            'label' => 'Przypisane usługi',
            'expanded' => true,
            'multiple' => true
        ])
    ;
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, выкиньте из вопроса весь тот код, что не имеет прямого отношения к делу. А то две портянки по over9000 строк - это перебор.

Comment: Извиняюсь, все исправил.

Comment: А где мэппинг сам? Этого недостаточно - /**
 * @var $mentors
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="services")
 */

Comment: А чего еще может не хватать здесь? Соединение таблиц на автомате делается, cascade вроде пока не нужен. Или в данном случае еще что то упускаю?

Comment: cascade persist попробуйте добавить, я так понимаю что Service  у вас в форме к сущности добавляется ?  Проверьте `$service = $form->getData()->getService()` после обработки формы, есть ли там нужная сущность? Ну и можете чтоб гвоздями прям - `$this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->persist($service);` перед flush(), раз уж ничего не помогает.

Comment: @zalex спасибо за помощь. Добавил cascade={"persist"} в сущности User - не помогло. Добавил в Service - тоже самое. Форма все данные получает, то есть из формы в контроллер сервисы нормально попадают. Теряются на уровне записи получается. `persist($service)` тоже делал, ни в какую. Попытался сделать addService в петле -  виснет браузер и уже войти на сайт невозможно без перезапуска.

Comment: persist($service) в данном случае весьма себе ошибочно ибо в $service хранится ArrayCollection в этом случае , так что там foreach , но на самом деле я ответ написал ниже, там ошибка в методе.

Answer (score 1):

Присмотрелся к коду, у вас там конечно ошибки.

Во первых название методов.  Если у вас поле `$mentors`, то называйте метод `addMentors()`, почему `addMentor` ? Доктрина откуда об этом знает ? Форма, я подозреваю угадывает, но доктрина не факт что так умеет.

Вот этот метод тоже вызывает сомнение

```
public function addMentor(\AppBundle\Entity\User $mentor)
{
    $mentor->addService($this);
}
```

Вы же должны добавить `$mentor` в коллекцию `$mentors`, по сему

```
public function addMentors(\AppBundle\Entity\User $mentor)
{
    $this->mentors->add($mentor);
}
```

Далее доктрина как раз из этого поля должна забрать новый элемент коллекции и если указан каскад — делать `persist` автоматом. Если каскада нет, по-моему она выдаст ошибку и сообщит, что каскад стоило бы добавить.

В общем, посмотрите внимательно название методом и то, что я написал по поводу поля.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. По сути все эти методы Доктрин автоматом самолично сгенерировал. `doctrine:generate:entities AppBundle:User`. Сейчас попробую поменять названия методов и проверю.

Comment: Честно говоря я не думаю что Doctrine умеет корректно генерить методы для отношений или умеет ? Судя по тому что у вас не работает - не умеет.

Comment: Кстати, как раз, приведенный в примере метод `addMentor` работает как следует. То есть к Сервису я без проблем могу приписать любое колличество юзеров(менторов). Но входя в Юзера и пытаясь приписать ему Сервисы, это уже не работает. Но сейчас исправлю названия, и проверю. Насчет умений Доктрины вообще сказать ничего не могу, я новичек пока что.

Comment: Нет, послушайте, метод `addMentor` в вашем случае добавляет в `$mentor` `$this` , т.е. `service`, вам же надо в этом метода добавить `$mentor`  в коллекцию  `$mentors`

Comment: Все верно, я удалил по видимости случайно добавление. Но все равно ничего так и не работает, после возвращения. Может я обновлю шапку? чтобы было видно как сейчас код выглядит? Серьезно, не знаю уже на что сетовать...

Comment: Обновите конечно, чудес ведь не бывает, где то какая то мелкая ошибка, как это всегда бывает. А ещё форму бы посмотреть.

Comment: Обновил, добавил еще buildForm

Comment: Надобно еще учесть, что User  у вас наследует BaseUser, а значит у него есть какие то обязательные поля для заполнения без которых он попросту не зайдет в базу, но вот не знаю, выдает ли доктрина ошибку в этом случае. Еще посмотрите в логах, возможно что то найдете.

Comment: Вообще никаких ошибок не показывает. В логах тоже никакой информации особенной. Но если меняю email или имя, то все меняется. Только сервисы так и не добавляются. Для интереса добавил два вида методов, те, что Вы посоветовали и что Доктрин сам создает. Ноль...